# How to call a method from programmatically created buttons with different parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, click, raise

my problem is how to call a existing method from another object with button specific parameters.
This is the method I need to call ( from MainWindow):

```
partial class Sidebar : Window
{
    [...]
    internal void SetPosition(System.Drawing.Rectangle workingarea, bool left)
    {
      Overlay.Properties.Settings.Default.SidebarSide = left;
      Overlay.Properties.Settings.Default.Top = this.Top = workspace.Top;
      Overlay.Properties.Settings.Default.Left = this.Left = workspace.Left;
      Overlay.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      this.Height = workspace.Height;
      this.Width = workspace.Width;
      timeGrid.Style = gridStyle;
      Refresh();
    }
    [...]
}
```

and following is the method for creating buttons (and more) for each Screen connected to the machine

```
class SettingsWindow : Window
{
    [...]
    private void SidebarTab_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Canvas monitorCanvas = new Canvas();
                spPosition.Children.Add(monitorCanvas);

            System.Windows.Forms.Screen currentScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(
                new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;

            Point min = new Point(0,0);
            Point max = new Point(0,0);

            for (int i = 0; i < screens.Length; i++)
            {
                min.X = min.X < screens[i].Bounds.X ? min.X : screens[i].Bounds.X;
                min.Y = min.Y < screens[i].Bounds.Y ? min.Y : screens[i].Bounds.Y;

                max.X = max.X > (screens[i].Bounds.X + screens[i].Bounds.Width) ? max.X : (screens[i].Bounds.X + screens[i].Bounds.Width);
                max.Y = max.Y > (screens[i].Bounds.Y + screens[i].Bounds.Height) ? max.Y : (screens[i].Bounds.Y + screens[i].Bounds.Height);
            }
            [...]


            for (int i = 0; i < screens.Length; i++)
            {

                Border monitor = new Border();
                monitor.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                monitor.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                Canvas.SetTop(monitor, (screens[i].Bounds.Top - min.Y) / scale);
                Canvas.SetLeft(monitor, (screens[i].Bounds.Left - min.X) / scale);
                monitor.Width = screens[i].Bounds.Width / scale;
                monitor.Height = screens[i].Bounds.Height / scale;

                DockPanel dp = new DockPanel();

                Button monLeft = new Button();
                monLeft.Width = scale;
                DockPanel.SetDock(monLeft, Dock.Left);

                Button monRight = new Button();
                monRight.Width = scale;
                DockPanel.SetDock(monRight, Dock.Right);
                [...]
                }
            }

}
```

As you see, I need two buttons for every screen on the machine. 
`monLeft.Click = SetPosition(screens[i].WorkingArea, true);` and 
`monRight.Click = SetPosition(screens[i].WorkingArea, true);` is what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda to define the event handler.  This allows you to close over the local variable(s) that you'll need in your handler.

Note that closures close over variables, not values, so you don't want to close over `i` (it won't be the value that you want it to be by the time the event fires).  You'll need to make a copy of the loop variable inside of the loop so that you can close over *that* instead.  Well, that or use a `foreach` loop (in C# 5.0+) instead of a `for` loop.

```
foreach(var screen in screens)
{
    //...

    Button monRight = new Button();
    monRight.Width = scale;
    DockPanel.SetDock(monRight, Dock.Right);
    monRight.Click += (s,e) => SetPosition(screen.WorkingArea, true);
}
```

Comment: thank you, the thing i was missing with this was copying the  variable. So that hint helped me most.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you can see in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx, `Button.Click` is an event, so you need to assign an event handler to it:

Either you wrap your `SetPosition()` method in an event handler and assign the event handler of your `Button.Click` event to it, or you can do it through lambda construction as suggested in the previous answer.

Another alternative is setting the `Button.Command` for your buttons, by implementing an instance of `ICommand` that will call the `SetPosition()` method.

Comment: well, that where the information found in Internet, helpful at some place if i wouldn't know what to look after. but i appreciate your help

Comment: Well, the idea was to show to you that you were incorrectly using the `Click` event. Moreover, I also provided information on how to use `Button.Command`. But I'm glad you found a solution! :)